# How to "grab" all submissions from a subreddit?

Tags: python, praw

I'm writing a simple python script to get all of a subreddit's submission titles and bodies.

```
for submission in sub.new()
    title = submission.title
    text = submission.selftext
```

The script only loops through 12 submissions before ending (with no error output). `sub.hot()` also stops at 12 submissions. There are a few hundred submissions in the sub (r/dailyprogrammer)

I'm new to [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and don't know if this is the result of a limit on how many submissions I can "get" or if it is related to using `.new()` and `.hot()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work in most recent version of PRAW but try:

```
for submission in sub.get_new(limit=300):
```